# Background color change (every second a slight change)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity

Can anyone please tell me how to implement the background which slightly change every second as shown in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nwoS.png).

Comment: this is processing bar or Progress at execution of any method . m i correct.

Comment: you have need to do it by creation custom dialog then you can do it

Comment: @amitsharma  can use please tell me the exact way to implement it

Comment: this is shown in your pic or image its your question so u have need to enplane his question in details

Comment: no buddy are sit here to give you solution of your requirements Do something his self then if you have need to get small help then someones can help you ......

Comment: Have you look how much negative marks here at your question...Look his manner to ask question ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This May Help You

```
ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(**myView**, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE);

            colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
            colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
            colorAnim.start();
```

Where myView is the view on which you want to apply Animation

Comment: Can you please tell me that how to set background color in the rainbow color format as shown in http://pasteboard.co/3F7qNeP.png

Comment: use this site   http://angrytools.com/gradient/   to generate gradient style with multiple colors